# SQL Server Integration Services - How to get the current date and generate a filename with it in .dtsConfig File

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I developed a dataflow for create a csv file getting the data from a database in SSIS.

I have created the Connection Manager for the Flat File Destination but I need to change the filename dinamically adding at the end of it the current date.

Currently I gotta this:

```
   <Configuration ConfiguredType="Property" Path="\Package.Connections[csv_conf].Properties[ConnectionString]" ValueType="String">
      <ConfiguredValue>C:\Users\Desktop\SSISfacturacion\test.csv</ConfiguredValue>
   </Configuration>
```

for example, today it would be named test-20210716.csv

Any idea about how can I do it?

Comment: Are you *really* sure you want to go this route? The configuration route is only read when the package begins running so you would need to have a package that runs before the actual to generate the expected value in the config file.

Comment: A much, *much*, more common practice would be to set an Expression on the `ConnectionString` property of the Flat File Connection Manager and then use a Variable that makes the fully qualified path.

Comment: Final comment, locating the file in the Users folder path is likely going to cause issues when it moves out of your local development to a server as the service account likely does not have access to that structure